# monitor specific action to specific table SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know current update, insert , select on specific table.

I have used sql server profiler but don't know how to filter. When filter by sqltext, It include many noisy things example the query update on others table but it select data from table which I want to monitors I don't want  this show up . Just exactly the update on table A or B.

I am using SQL 2008 R2

Thanks

Comment: You can have a trigger on the table to capture any change

Comment: agree with @PSK you can set trigger on particular table, and insert in some other audit log table, to see the respective CRUD operation on table.

Comment: Trigger is a way, but may be it slow down performance , I know CDC solution but It already use in my system can not modify it . So we can not do it by SQL PROFILER ?